# Mariadb 10.3.8: Installation from MariaDB repo , missing files?

Tags: mariadb

I've installed MariaDB 10.3.8 on Ubuntu 18 Server, as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0xF1656F24C74CD1D8
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,arm64,ppc64el] http://sfo1.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.3/ubuntu bionic main'
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mariadb-server
sudo apt install mariadb-client
```

It does not start:

```
sudo service mariadb start
Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Log:

```
systemctl status mariadb.service
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.8 database server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-07-12 20:18:48 PDT; 46s ago
   Docs: man:mysqld(8)
       https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
  Process: 3392 ExecStartPost=/etc/mysql/debian-start (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
  Process: 3359 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3349 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`/usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]
  Process: 3342 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Process: 3332 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Main PID: 3359 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Status: "MariaDB server is down"

Then, I see a file that is missing:

```
sudo ls -l /etc/mysql/debian-start
ls: cannot access '/etc/mysql/debian-start': No such file or directory
```

Other files missing:

```
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
/etc/mysql/conf.d
/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf
/etc/init.d/mysql
```

Comment: I copied the missing files from a previous backup  ( I had backed up some mysql files ) , and MariaDB is running now. Still.. I do not know how to properly install the files I listed as missing (from which package do they come?)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found a solution:

The following command:

```
apt-get install --reinstall -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" mariadb-server-10.3
```

Created some files:

```
/etc/mysql/conf.d
/etc/init.d/mysql
/etc/mysql/debian-start
```

And:

```
apt-get install --reinstall -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" mysql-common
```

Created:

```
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Comment: After purging and reinstalling everything, this was the only solution that helped me get the server running again!

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.04 and mariadb-server-10.6 I am getting the same error (missing stuff in /etc/mysql) The above command with version 10.6 just solved that single error.